# Only mark issue as resolved when a commit is merged to the main branch?

Tags: git, bitbucket

When I close an Bitbucket ticket in a commit message (such as `fixes #70`), the issue gets closed even though the fix is not yet merged to the main branch (as set in Bitbucket settings). Is it possible to postpone the close action until the commit is properly merged?

Answer (score 1):

It seems this is not possible with BitBucket.

They don't mention anything about the commit being pushed to the main branch in the [respective documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/resolve-issues-automatically-when-users-push-code-221451126.html).

You can create a feature request in their Jira dashboard - https://jira.atlassian.com/secure/Dashboard.jspa

Or you can use GitHub which [does support it](https://help.github.com/articles/closing-issues-via-commit-messages/):

> For example, a commit message with Fixes #45 will close issue 45 in that repository once the commit is merged into the default branch.
>
> If the commit is in a non-default branch, the issue will remain open and the issue will be referenced with a tooltip.